# How to run External Tools by clicking an icon

Tags: eclipse

I want to run a batch file from Eclipse. I managed to do that using **External Tools**. Now it would be great if I am able to run .bat from tool bar by clicking some icon. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

1. Run --> External Tools --> Organize  Favourite..
2. Press Add and choose the external tools configuration that you created for this .bat
3. OK

Then you can run this .bat from tool bar  by clicking the following icon :

[image]

Comment: Works smoothly. Thank you. What about one click if there is more than one bat file? I have only one right now so one click works for me.

Comment: You are welcome , but I also have no idea how to customize the eclipse toolbar to add an icon to it.